# Why this question does not meet quality standards

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask this question in Movies Private Beta, but when I Post my question, it gives an error saying,

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> It does not meet our quality standards.

Can someone explain why my question is rejected? (Sorry about my stupidity....)

This is the question I wanted to ask:

**Title**

> 'Blue Valentine' movie ending

**Question**

> At the end of the movie do they (Dean & Cindy) separate?  or Any other
>   thoughts you got about the movie ending?

**Tags**

> ending

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The overall word (character) length is short so the filter must have picked up on that and other things that I am not aware of in the system of SE.

*What are you trying to determine, a certain outcome? Maybe phrase it as follows,*

> Title: Outcome of relationship at the end of 'Blue Valentine'
>
> Always put meat into the title.
>
> Body:
>
> I have not watched this movie so this a todo section for you.
>
> - Place in a little spoiler section to jog the memory of those who did see
> - Explain your research for and against why you think the separation occurred (camera placements, character expressions .. etc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Posted question succesfully... http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51/outcome-of-relationship-at-the-end-of-blue-valentine

Comment: no problem @Nalaka526